# How to exit hotkey function and continue the script (AutoHotKey)?

Tags: return, autohotkey

Thanks for reading. :)

Let's give an example of what I say. I press shift+g and I execute one function. In the middle of executing it, I want to stop it by pressing shift+h, then execute another function, and then return the script so as it to stay waiting for another keystroke.

I thought about reloading the program, but I couldn't execute the following commands that way. Or, I could execute another program and reload the first one, but it is getting too complicated.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put the script in a separate file and run it as an external program. Use #SingleInstance Force to be sure only one copy is running, and if you want to kill it use Process, Close with the PID you can get back from the Run statement.

I do this all the time with long complicated scripts that fail frequently. I mostly do that so if the script fails I just hit the hotkey again to restart. It kills the first instance and restarts. Interrupting a running script is just another special case.

Note that you'll need to run AutoHotkey.exe and pass the name of the script and any parameters. Don't try to run the script itself.

Answer (score -2):

As pointed out the easiest way is to put the script in a separate file and run it as an external program. something like this:

```
RunWait %A_AhkPath% test1.ahk
```

Then in test1.apk put ExitApp in a hotkey. like this:

```
+t::
msgbox killing myself!
Exitapp
```

very simple!